# Video decoding in UWP

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, m3u8

I have application that can play .m3u8 files.
However, when video encoded with `MPEG 1/2 (mpgv)`, it's only show blank screen. When opening video like `H.264`, everything is OK. What's wrong?

Here's code:

```
using Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming;


//Listing: MainPage.xaml.cs -> class
private MediaExtensionManager extensions;
private PropertySet propertySet;
private IAdaptiveSourceManager adaptiveSourceManager;


//Listing: MainPage.xaml.cs -> class -> constructor
propertySet = new PropertySet();
extensions = new MediaExtensionManager();
adaptiveSourceManager = AdaptiveSourceManager.GetDefault();
propertySet["{A5CE1DE8-1D00-427B-ACEF-FB9A3C93DE2D}"] = adaptiveSourceManager;
extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "text/xml", propertySet);
extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml", propertySet);
extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "application/x-mpegurl", propertySet);
extensions.RegisterByteStreamHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothByteStreamHandler", ".ism", "video/mp2t", propertySet);
extensions.RegisterSchemeHandler("Microsoft.Media.AdaptiveStreaming.SmoothSchemeHandler", "ms-sstr:", propertySet);



//Listing -> MainPage.xaml.cs -> OnNavigatedTo method
//Getting manifest.m3u8
var link = new Uri("path_to_remote_m3u8_file");
Player.Source = link;
Player.Play();


//Listing: MainPage.xaml
<MediaElement x:Name="Player" />
```

Generally, in `.m3u8` we have list of `.ts` files. But those which was encoded with `H.264` can be played, and those which was encoded by `MPEG-1` or `MPEG-2` cannot.

I guess I need to add more handlers to `extensions` or maybe I should you `Microsoft Player Framework`, but they don't have `Dash plugin` for windows 10, so following [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/flecoqui/2014/05/28/building-audiovideo-applications-based-on-player-framework-v2-0-for-windows-phone-8-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone-8-1/) example I cannot accomplish result. Or maybe FFmpeg?

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 doesn't support natively MPEG2 video codec.

Nevertheless, Windows 10 does support natively :

- HLS
- MPEG DASH (Live Profile)

It's also support Smooth Streaming if you use the Smooth Streaming Client SDK for Windows 10.

You used a link to my blog which is related to Windows 8.1 not Windows 10. You'll find a sample of an Universal Video Player on my github, supporting DASH, HLS and Smooth Streaming + PlayReady DRM: 
https://github.com/flecoqui/Windows10/tree/master/Samples/UniversalMediaPlayer

This sample application is compliant with PC, Tablet, Phone and XBOX One running Windows 10.

If you want to play MPEG2 content maybe you could use VLC. VLC does support MPEG2 codec.
Try the VLC 3.0 nightly build
http://nightlies.videolan.org/build/win32/
VLC 3.0 should be RTM soon.

Let me know if I answered your question

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not able to open my `MPEG-2` file, so I will searching for another solution.